# How render form with previously entered data when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters, render

I'm doing www.theodinproject.com [Project: Forms](https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/forms?ref=lnav). If the new User fails to validate, it should `render :new` with the previous entered data. My code works to save new users and it `render :new` when validations fails, but the previously entered data is missing.

Tried to research the solution myself but couldn't resolve it. I apologize if a similar question had been posted.

My routes

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

my user controller

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    # @user = User.new(username: params[:username], email: params[:email], password: params[:password])
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to new_user_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
  end

end
```

and my new.html.erb

```rb
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">
  <label for="user[username]">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="user[username]"><br>
  <label for="user[email]">email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="user[email]"><br>
  <label for="user[password]">password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="user[password]"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never setting the input's values. I'd suggest you use rails' form helpers like `form_for` and the rest. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= label :username %>
  <%= text_field :username %>
  <%= label :email %>
  <%= text_field :email %>
  <%= label :password %>
  <%= password_field :password %>
  <%= submit %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: there's even a section on the tutorial you linked that tells you to use form_for :S

Comment: Thanks for the input @arieljuod. I'm aware that later in the tutorial it tells me to use the rails form helper `form_for`. What gets me confused is that the tutorial suggest that `render :new` should display the previously entered data before the `form_for` section. Is it maybe an error of the tutorial suggesting that?

Comment: I guess it's an error on the tutorial. You could do it withouth using `form_for` by setting the values manually like `<input type="text" name="user[username]" value="<%= @user.username %>">` though.

Comment: @quilmes the odin project lets you work through this thing manually to better understand what the rails form helper does, so things become a little less magic, and a bit more understandable. I would encourage you to try again without the form_for helper using the method aireljuod just described. Good luck! Also its always a good idea to checkout other students solution if you are stuck.